# QuantLib: Swap to zero-coupon curve bootstrapping

Tags: python, quantlib

I'm trying to bootstrap the US swap curve into a zero coupon curve (see Bloomberg screenshot). I have daily data for maturities 3M, 1Y, 2Y, 5Y, 7Y, 10Y from 21/06/1996 to today (with some days missing, see DataFrame screenshot). I would like to obtain the corresponding zero rates for all maturities ranging from 3M to 10Y.

[Bloomberg Screenshot of the 5Y US Swap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wayOY.png)

[Swap curve data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRb3A.png)

Here's the piece of code I have written:

```
zero_rates = {}
helpers_mat =[]
# loop over time
for t in range(irs.shape[0]):
    # date of pricing (= DataFrame index line by line)
    pricing_date = ql.DateParser.parseFormatted(str(irs.index[t]),'%Y-%m-%d')
    # define evaluation date
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = pricing_date
    # list of maturities and corresponding swap rates
    for m in irs.columns:
        helpers_mat.append([(m, ql.Months), irs[m][t]])

    # helper function to intput details
    helpers = [ql.SwapRateHelper(
                           ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100.0)),
                           ql.Period(*tenor),
                           ql.TARGET(),
                           ql.Semiannual,
                           ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                           ql.Thirty360(),
                           ql.Euribor3M())
                           for tenor, rate in helpers_mat]

    # build zero-coupon curve (cubic spline interpolation)
    zc_curve = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(pricing_date, helpers, ql.Actual360())
    # pre-allocate
    zero_rate = []
    tenors = []
    # loop over wanted maturities
    for n in np.arange(3, 120+1, 3):
        # maturities
        yrs = n/12.0
        tenors.append(yrs)
        # extract zero-coupon rate
        zc_rate = zc_curve.zeroRate(yrs, ql.Compounded, ql.Annual).rate()
        zero_rate.append(zc_rate*100)
        # pandas export
        zero_rates[t] = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(list(zip(zero_rate))), columns = list(zip(tenors)), 
        index = [irs.index[t]])

zero_rates = pd.concat(zero_rates, axis=0)
```

With that code, I obtain the following error:

*RuntimeError: more than one instrument with pillar July 25th, 1996*

So I guess I have an issue with dates. My understanding is that the *SwapRateHelper* takes the characteristics of the fixed leg of the swap. **But where do I input the floating leg's ones?**

Answer (score 0):

The float leg parameters come from the index. In your case, it seems you are using ql.Euribor3M() which is close enough to the USD Libor 3M which is what you really want. The difference would basically be the wrong calendar.

However, not knowing the shape of you data makes it hard to figure out what is wrong.

There are many different ways to build the helpers and for a USD curve you might as well just use the USDLibor index for deposits and the ql.UsdLiborSwapIsdaFixAm for the swap.

Check if this example I made based on your data helps...

```
import pandas as pd
import QuantLib as ql

data = [
    {'Date': '1996-06-21 00:00:00', '3M': 5.57813, '1Y': 6.19, '2Y': 6.55, '5Y': 7.02, '7Y': 7.17, '10Y': 7.31},
    {'Date': '1996-06-24 00:00:00', '3M': 5.56641, '1Y': 6.18, '2Y': 6.54, '5Y': 6.99, '7Y': 7.14, '10Y': 7.31},
    {'Date': '1996-06-25 00:00:00', '3M': 5.5625, '1Y': 6.155, '2Y': 6.52, '5Y': 6.99, '7Y': 7.15, '10Y': 7.31},
    {'Date': '1996-06-26 00:00:00', '3M': 5.57031, '1Y': 6.14, '2Y': 6.52, '5Y': 6.94, '7Y': 7.1, '10Y': 7.27},
    {'Date': '1996-06-27 00:00:00', '3M': 5.59766, '1Y': 6.16, '2Y': 6.5, '5Y': 6.93, '7Y': 7.09, '10Y': 7.26},
    {'Date': '1996-06-28 00:00:00', '3M': 5.58203, '1Y': 6.075, '2Y': 6.44, '5Y': 6.87, '7Y': 7.03, '10Y': 7.2},
    {'Date': '1996-07-01 00:00:00', '3M': 5.5625, '1Y': 6.03, '2Y': 6.33, '5Y': 6.75, '7Y': 6.92, '10Y': 7.09},
    {'Date': '1996-07-02 00:00:00', '3M': 5.5625, '1Y': 6.05, '2Y': 6.36, '5Y': 6.77, '7Y': 6.93, '10Y': 7.11},
    {'Date': '1996-07-03 00:00:00', '3M': 5.59766, '1Y': 6.11, '2Y': 6.43, '5Y': 6.84, '7Y': 7.0, '10Y': 7.17},
    {'Date': '1996-07-04 00:00:00', '3M': 5.57031, '1Y': 6.07, '2Y': 6.37, '5Y': 6.79, '7Y': 6.95, '10Y': 7.13},
    {'Date': '1996-07-05 00:00:00', '3M': 5.57422, '1Y': 6.075, '2Y': 6.4, '5Y': 6.8, '7Y': 6.96, '10Y': 7.13},
    {'Date': '1996-07-08 00:00:00', '3M': 5.6875, '1Y': 6.33, '2Y': 6.69, '5Y': 7.11, '7Y': 7.27, '10Y': 7.44},
    {'Date': '1996-07-09 00:00:00', '3M': 5.6875, '1Y': 6.31, '2Y': 6.64, '5Y': 7.07, '7Y': 7.23, '10Y': 7.41},
    {'Date': '1996-07-10 00:00:00', '3M': 5.6875, '1Y': 6.28, '2Y': 6.545, '5Y': 6.985, '7Y': 7.145, '10Y': 7.325},
    {'Date': '1996-07-11 00:00:00', '3M': 5.6875, '1Y': 6.22, '2Y': 6.465, '5Y': 6.925, '7Y': 7.085, '10Y': 7.255},
    {'Date': '1996-07-12 00:00:00', '3M': 5.67578, '1Y': 6.17, '2Y': 6.465, '5Y': 6.905, '7Y': 7.055, '10Y': 7.225},
    {'Date': '1996-07-15 00:00:00', '3M': 5.67578, '1Y': 6.19, '2Y': 6.485, '5Y': 6.925, '7Y': 7.075, '10Y': 7.245},
    {'Date': '1996-07-16 00:00:00', '3M': 5.68359, '1Y': 6.22, '2Y': 6.425, '5Y': 6.855, '7Y': 7.025, '10Y': 7.205}
]

calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
zeros = []
deposits = ['3M']
swaps = ['1Y', '2Y', '5Y', '7Y', '10Y']
for row in data:
    # Build Curve for the date
    curve_date = ql.Date(row['Date'][:10], '%Y-%m-%d')
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = curve_date
    spot_date = calendar.advance(curve_date, 2, ql.Days)
    helpers = ql.RateHelperVector()
    for tenor in deposits:
        index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period(tenor))
        helpers.append(
            ql.DepositRateHelper(row[tenor] / 100, index)
        )
    for tenor in swaps:
        swap_index = ql.UsdLiborSwapIsdaFixAm(ql.Period(tenor))
        helpers.append(
            ql.SwapRateHelper(row[tenor] / 100, swap_index)
        )
    curve = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(curve_date, helpers, ql.Actual360())

    # Get Zero Rates
    for tenor in deposits + swaps:
        date = calendar.advance(spot_date, ql.Period(tenor))
        rate = curve.zeroRate(date, ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Annual).rate()
        zeros.append({ 'curve_date': curve_date, 'tenor': tenor, 'zero_rate': rate})

pd.DataFrame(zeros)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options when defining a deposit helper.

Imagine you have the following parameters:

```
tenor = ql.Period('6M')
fixingDays = 2
calendar = ql.SouthAfrica()
convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
endOfMonth = False
dayCounter = ql.Actual365Fixed()
```

(i) Either create a custom index instead of using the available templates. Here you will have to give it the relevant parameters.

```
myindex = ql.IborIndex('MyIndex', tenor, fixingDays, currency, calendar, convention, endOfMonth, dayCounter)
helper = ql.DepositRateHelper(rate, myindex)
```

(ii) Or define all these parameters in the DepositHelper:

```
helper = ql.DepositRateHelper(rate, tenor, fixingDays, calendar, convention, endOfMonth, dayCounter)
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I found the following generic attributes that match the theoretical calculations:

calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
fixedLegDayCounter = ql.SimpleDayCounter().

One last question though: what is the use of currency in the ql.IborIndex if everything is specified in the other arguments?